# Get list of files from URL iOS

Tags: ios, file, url

Im working on an app that now has to go to a URL online and read all filenames inside a folder and get them into the app for parsing.  How do I achieve this in iOS?  Ive looked at NSURLConnection and didn't find anything.

Comment: Do you mean a) you want to load a URL and parse all the files which are linked in the URL and in the folder b) load a directory (without an index file) and parse all the files which are listed?

Comment: Because you can't load a URL and parse all the files inside the folder... If the folder has no index file and you load the directory, the files will be listed and it is possible. However, if you load the specific page, you will only be able to see the files in the folder which are linked to the page; no other files in the folder.

Comment: I want the app to fetch a list of files inside a folder and create an array with the filenames as objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this turns out to be a server side script!

Answer (score 0):

What didn't you find with NSURLConnection that you were looking for?

That would be one standard way of downloding a file using HTTP.

You *could* do this, but it is synchronous.

```
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: This gets the data for a specific file right?  I would need to gets list of files in order to test which ones I want to fetch.

Comment: I doubt you're going to find a handy (NSArray*) NSURLConnection:goToRemoteURLOfFolderAndGetContents: method. Look into using NSURLConnection in combination with FTP.